# File craching without reason

Tags: c, crash

what happens is during the gendersearch function when it reaches time to enter which gender i would like to see it skips the input then just crashes without giving a reason. the other functions work fine from what i can tell( ip ut it there just in case the error might of been because of one of them)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getinfo (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
  int y;
  for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
    nam[y] = malloc(50);
    printf ("What is the student's name?\t");
    scanf ("%s", nam[y]);
    printf ("\nWhat is the students age?\t");
    scanf ("%d", &ag[y]);
    printf ("\nwhat is the students gender, Male/Female\t");
    scanf (" %c", &gender[y]);
 }
}

void findeldest (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
    int largest = 0, y, eldest =0 ;
    for(y = 0; y < count; y++){
        if (ag[y] > eldest){
            largest = ag[y];
            eldest = y;
        }
     }
    printf ("The eldest student is:\t %s", nam[eldest]);
    printf ("\nGender:\t %c", gender[eldest]);
    printf ("\nWith an age of:\t %d \n", ag[eldest]);

}

void gendersearch (char* nam[],int ag[], char gender[], int count){
     int y;
     char choice;
     printf ("What gender would you like to see(male-m/female-f)?\n");
     scanf ("%c", choice);
     switch (choice){
            case 'm' : printf ("The male students are as follows:\n");
            case 'f' : printf ("The female students are as follows:\n");
            default : printf ("please enter m for male or f for female!\n");
     }
     if (choice == 'm'){
        for (y = 0 ; y < count; y++){                 
            if (gender[y] == choice){
               printf (nam[y]);
            }    
        }        
     }else{
          for (y = 0 ; y < count; y++){                 
            if (gender[y] == choice){
               printf (nam[y]);
            }    
          }  
     }
}

int main (){
  int amount, y;
  printf("How many students are you admitting?\t");
  scanf ("%d", &amount);
  char *name[50];
        int age[50];
        char gender[50];
  if (amount > 50){
      printf("Too many students!");
  }else{
        getinfo(name, age, gender, amount);
        findeldest(name, age, gender, amount);
  }
  gendersearch (name, age, gender, amount);
  system("pause");}
```

Comment: You might want some breaks after those cases.

Comment: i made all the corrections suggested and the problem still occurs

Comment: @RajayJB Code fixed as suggested works, please post a new question if you have problems with your new code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using scanf without & in `void gendersearch ()`

```
 scanf ("%c", choice);
```

change to:

```
 scanf ("%c", &choice);
```

Scanf requires the address of the variable not the value of it.

Comment: i made all the corrections suggested and the problem still occurs